# Failed post to group via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I got an error after posting to a Facebook in which I'm a member:

> Error: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the
>   group, and \ either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or
>   both manage_pages \ and publish_pages permission with page token; If
>   posting to a page, \ requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as
>   an admin with \ sufficient administrative permission

It works only in a Group where I had added an App that has permission "publish_to_groups". I have tested only with a text message.

Is there any way to Post a Video to multiple facebook groups where I'm a member via Facebook Graph?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only post in groups where an admin installed your app, just being a member of that group does not suffice.